# Dynamically creating image link Jquery or vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically create a image with caption below it. I would like it so that when a user clicks the image or caption it redirects to a different page. I have a feeling what I am doing is wrong on many levels.

```
function createFrame(data){
    // <div><a href=""><img src=""><div></div></img></a></div>
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var img = document.createElement('img'); 
    a = a.innerHTML(img);
    div.innerHTML(a);
    return div;
});
```

Comment: innerHTML is not a method

Comment: change innerHTML to appendChild ;)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `data` argument?

Comment: Passing in parsed JSON data that includes the image details

Comment: I am using brackets and the intellisense showed innerHTML is a method that is why I tried to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it with pure JS or with frameworks (jquery..).

Pure js :

Level 1 simple

```js
function createFrame(src){
  return "<div>"+
            "<a href='"+src+"' target='_blank'>"+
              "<img src='"+src+"' alt='demo'/>"+
            "</a>"+
          "</div>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = createFrame("http://lorempixel.com/100/100");
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<br/>
```

2nd Level

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = createFrame("http://lorempixel.com/100/100");

function createFrame(src=false, divID = false, link=false, aID=false, imgID=false, openToNewTab = false){
  $html = "";

  $html += "<div ";
  if(divID !== false) $html += "id = '"+divID+"' ";
  $html += ">";
  $html += " <a href='";
  $html += (link !== false)? link+"' ":"#' ";
  $html += (openToNewTab !== false)? " target='_blank'":"";
  $html += ">";
  $html += "<img src='"+src+"' ";
  $html += imgID? " id='"+imgID+"'":"";
  $html +=  " /></a></div>";
 return $html;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

3rd Level

```js
var html = createFrame(
                      {"src":"http:lorempixel.com/100/100", "id":"img"},// img attributes
                      {"href":"http:lorempixel.com/100/100", "class":"caption", "target":"_blank"}, // a attributes
                      {"class":"imgContainer"}//div
                      );
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;




function createFrame(img={}, a={}, div={}){
  var html = "";
  html  = TagGenerator("img", img, "",true);
  html  = TagGenerator("a", a, html);
  html  = TagGenerator("div", div, html);
 return html;
}



function TagGenerator(tagname, attr=[], html="", endAbleTag=false){
  var tag = "<"+tagname+" ", i;
  for (i in attr)
     tag += i+"='"+attr[i]+"' ";
  if(!endAbleTag) tag += ">"+html+" </"+tagname+">";
  else tag += "/>";
  return tag;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `.append()` in jquery, you can append the `image` tags in the desired div.

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
  $("#imgDiv").append('<a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="Image"/></a>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Create Image Link</button>

<div id="imgDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following your idea of creat that you want, i did the following:

```
function createFrame(data){
// <div><a href=""><img src=""><div></div></img></a></div>
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.href = 'your-href-link';
 var img = document.createElement('img'); 
 img.src  = 'your-src-link';
 var div_caption = document.createElement('div');
 a.appenchild(img);
 a.appenchild(div_caption);
 div.appenchild(a);
});
```