# require() throwing an exception when dynamically setting location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, require

I hit another Problem with my project that I cannot resolve or understand.

```
 useEffect(() => {
axios.get(API_BASE_URL + '/user/images', payload)
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            console.log("RESPONSE IMAGE:" + JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2));

            let files = response.data.files[0];
            const requirestring = "../../images/public/" + files;

            let requireimg;
            if(files == null){
               requireimg = require("../../images/basic-profile-picture.jpg");
            }else {
                try{
         >>           requireimg = require(requirestring);
                }catch (e){
                    requireimg = require("../../images/basic-profile-picture.jpg");
                }
            }
            setMapImages(<Image className={"profilepicture"} src={requireimg.default} alt={"TEXT"} />);
        } else {
            alert("error getting images");
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("DOWNLOAD: " + error);
    });
```

Why is this part:

```
  requireimg = require(requirestring);
```

throwing this exception:

```
Cannot find module '../../images/public/600bc441b2b2b62c542bd135_profilepicture.jpg'
```

But this works and isnt throwing an exception somehow:

```
 requireimg = require("../../images/public/600bc441b2b2b62c542bd135_profilepicture.jpg")
```

The exception first occurred when I set the image-name with an "_" for better syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This happen because require is not a JavaScript API native function, is a Node function.
So, when you try to run in browser, the browser can't recognize the require function with variable as argument.

See this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require) for more detailed information

Comment: Thanks. So how do I apply dynamic image-changes with variables in Javascript?

Comment: Follow this link, maybe can help you -> [StackOverFlow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446879/dynamically-creating-image-link-jquery-or-vanilla-javascript/45452255)

Comment: In above link, look the pure js method do create an img dynamically, you can substitute the concatened method to Template Literal, cleaner and easy to use.